# Automatically add domain suffix in google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, script, browser-addons

I sometimes use a personal proxy, which works by adding an address to the domain address of any website. For example, if I am browsing this webpage:

(1) http://www.awebsite.com/home/index.html

Then, to access it from my proxy, I just type:

(2) http://www.awebsite.com.myproxy.net/home/index.html

I want to automate this process. Basically, I would like to add a button to Google Chrome (my browser of choice), so that if I have address (1) open, clicking the button automatically switches to (2).

How can I do this?

Comment: I know what you're up to laddie.

Comment: @paradroid Know how to do it then?